# Getting a 404 page for the stream_url. All permissions are set

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Getting the track data with GET yields the normal results. But, the stream URL (with appended client-id) doesn't work.

Here are the important ones:

```
<sharing>public</sharing>
<streamable type="boolean">true</streamable>
<stream-url>http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/112288415/stream</stream-url>
```

I'm at a loss now, because everything should be good to go, and play with `SC.stream()`.

Comment: how long ago did you change the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue in my particular case. Our client had some arrangement with Soundcloud that fell outside of the norm, and they had disabled streams but the API still reported the sound as available. After some help from our client we were able to get proper streams... Sorry for a non-technical solution!

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here for an answer to this problem, it is a known bug when a song reports `streamable: true` yet results in a blank white page in browser when trying to stream. The bug is in the streamable boolean being false.

Email response from SoundCloud on this issue:

> The developers have let me know that the problems you are having is
>   due to issues with RTMP.
>
> Currently certain content on SoundCloud is using a secure streaming
>   method called RTMP.
>
> To explain RTMP, even if a track is set to public and streamable by
>   the artist, if the artist is under a major label, this label can
>   further control those streaming permissions. So, it looks like it
>   should stream correctly, however it doesn't.
>
> This particular bug that you have highlighted is more complicated than
>   originally thought, and as only a handful of tracks are affected we
>   unfortunately don't have the resources to dedicate a team entirely to
>   this project as of right now.

So unfortunately you'll just have to deal with/work around this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add ?client_id=YourClientID to the url when you're requesting the stream.

Comment: I know. I mentioned "But, the stream URL (with appended client-id) doesn't work."

Comment: this looks like a problem with this track. if this is your track, delete it and re-upload.