# SoundCloud API Streaming fail blank page

Tags: soundcloud

There seems to be a silent fail when trying to stream tracks from an account.

Example:

API Gee console:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/#####.json?consumer_key=###
Response: 200
Streamable: true

API Console Stream URL:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/#####/stream?consumer_key=###
404 not found - (Blank white page no error in browser)

Track set to public and API streamable - All tracks on account, which were streaming as normal until the end of last week.

The consumer key works for tracks by other users, so it could be linked to this account directly?

Comment: Just seen someone else with the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100377/getting-a-404-page-for-the-stream-url-all-permissions-are-set

And also this looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852634/soundcloud-api-why-are-stream-urls-for-a-particular-artist-not-working-anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those coming here for an answer to this problem, it is a known bug when a song reports `streamable: true` yet results in a blank white page in browser when trying to stream. The bug is in the streamable boolean being false.

Email response from SoundCloud on this issue:

> The developers have let me know that the problems you are having is
>   due to issues with RTMP.
>
> Currently certain content on SoundCloud is using a secure streaming
>   method called RTMP.
>
> To explain RTMP, even if a track is set to public and streamable by
>   the artist, if the artist is under a major label, this label can
>   further control those streaming permissions. So, it looks like it
>   should stream correctly, however it doesn't.
>
> This particular bug that you have highlighted is more complicated than
>   originally thought, and as only a handful of tracks are affected we
>   unfortunately don't have the resources to dedicate a team entirely to
>   this project as of right now.

So unfortunately you'll just have to deal with/work around this issue.

Comment: a "handful" of tracks?? you mean every popular song on Soundcloud..  this is such a horrible response from a respectable site.

Comment: Yeah sadly so, one of the reasons I stopped using their api unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that i get blank page for stream url of tracks which are in "wav" format:

```
<original-format>wav</original-format>
```

other formats were working fine.

Comment: Interesting, but can't be the case because tracks which were previously streaming are not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what track you're trying to stream. Some tracks are set by the artist to not be streamed.

You got the format for the url correct. Try this url with your own `consumer key`:

`http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/32476280/stream?consumer_key=[###]`

Comment: That's the same url format I've been using. When clicking on that URL directly the page returns white with no errors.

Comment: Perhaps try getting a new consumer key from SoundCloud. I use this API everyday for a personal app and haven't had any problems. Also, try different tracks. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After being in touch with the support team at SoundCloud, they provided the following:

> The problems you are having is due to the content and rights holders.
>
> To explain, profile admins have the ability to change settings as they
>   like, so if the tracks have stopped playing, it's likely that they
>   have disabled apps on the track or content. This means that the rights
>   holders, that own all of this content, have turned this setting off,
>   and we don't have control over it or the ability to enable it again.

They managed to get my "API permissions extended" because the rights holders own the SoundCloud account in question. It seems there was just a mistake somewhere along the way with denying streaming.

You'll need to log an issue with SoundCloud support if you have a similar problem.