# Soundcloud stream_url returning a blank page

Tags: stream, soundcloud

With apps enabled and track set to public, the track will not load and just return a blank page:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123737611/stream?client_id=9f9f3e2d2545c59bab31a850ca4191b3

The soundcloud page I'm trying to stream from is here: https://soundcloud.com/capital-cities

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Bug, as referenced in other StackOverflow posts.

Has not been acknowledged, and still no reply on an email sent out to them.

[SoundCloud API Streaming fail blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102326/soundcloud-api-streaming-fail-blank-page)

[Getting a 404 page for the stream_url. All permissions are set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100377/getting-a-404-page-for-the-stream-url-all-permissions-are-set)

Email sent Thu, Jan 2, 2014. No reply.